# Python 2.6 run time error

Tags: python-2.6

STEPCAFControl which is available in python2.6 but webgl module is not available. So I am trying to run this below program .

```
            from __future__ import print_function

            import sys
            from OCC.STEPCAFControl import STEPCAFControl_Reader
            from OCC.STEPControl import STEPControl_Reader
            from OCC.IFSelect import IFSelect_RetDone, IFSelect_ItemsByEntity
            from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import init_display
            #from OCC.Display.WebGl import threejs_renderer


            step_reader = STEPControl_Reader()
            status = step_reader.ReadFile('./models/screw.step')

            if status == IFSelect_RetDone:  # check status
                failsonly = False
                step_reader.PrintCheckLoad(failsonly, IFSelect_ItemsByEntity)
                step_reader.PrintCheckTransfer(failsonly, IFSelect_ItemsByEntity)

                ok = step_reader.TransferRoot(1)
                _nbs = step_reader.NbShapes()
                aResShape = step_reader.Shape(1)
                print("Success")
            else:
                print("Error: can't read file.")
                sys.exit(0)


            display, start_display, add_menu, add_function_to_menu = init_display()
            display.DisplayShape(aResShape, update=True)
            start_display()

            #my_renderer = threejs_renderer.ThreejsRenderer(background_color="#123345")
            #my_renderer.DisplayShape(aResShape)
```

but getting this error.
[image]

How to solve this issue? Any suggestion?

Comment: That looks like a run time error to me.

Comment: Right.. How to solve this issue?